# Rails: POST API with Nested JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, api

I have created an API that requires a POST using JSON. This API is used to create multiple new items during a request. I am trying to extract specific information within the JSON shown below.

The JSON structure looks as follows:

```
{ "Items": [ {"item_id": 1 }, { "item_id": 2 }. { "item_id": 3 }, ...  ] }
```

Inside the controller, I have the following:

```
def create
    all_items = params[:items]
    ... 
    # Need something here to extract the item_id's from all_items and 
    # saved into a variable called item_id
    # Possibly a loop to do this
    new_item = Item.new(item_id)
    new_item.save
    render :json => {'Message' => 'Successfully created #{item_id}'}.to_json, :status => 200
end
```

I have tried using the `ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(all_items)`, however I get an error saying `cant convert Array into String`. Not sure if I need to use this though.

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: How does it do the POST action? Can you provide the form or ajax code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
all_items.each do |item|
  new_item = Item.new(item["item_id"])
  new_item.save
end
```